# Wheel Build spoke length

Tags: wheels, spokes

I want to get a wheel built using the components below:

https://www.ryde.nl/andra-40

https://bike.shimano.com/pt-PT/product/component/nexus-c3000-int7/SG-C3001-7D.html

The 36 spokes version,  3 cross pattern.

What is the length of the spokes I should use?

Thank you.

Comment: Just insert the relevant numbers into a calculator like this one: https://spokes-calculator.dtswiss.com/en/calculator

Answer (score 3):

To answer this question, you need some measurements.

The rim ERD, from the Ryde website.

The centre-to flange (left and right) measurements of the hub and the spoke hole circle diameter. These you may need to measure yourself as they are not always published.

This information is then entered into software (or a website) that performs the spoke length calculation for you. You could do this manually if you prefer but I often use the EDD spoke calculator or the one at kstoerz.com

Would you like any help making the measurements?

Comment: The website posts ERD

Comment: A note about ERD: the diameter is modified by what you consider acceptable spoke protrusion or depth at the nipple, perhaps even by nipple model. If you're using different nipples than what the ERD measurement is for, the values could affect optimal spoke length. So treat every "official" ERD measurement with a grain of salt. Also, it isn't completely uncommon for hub manufacturer to state values for hub measurements that are slightly off.

Comment: It's true that ERD is different between manufacturers. Ryde give a good value usually and for a standard pattern using brass nipples you shouldn't worry too much. Most spokes come in 2mm increments so you have a margin for error. If using alloy nipples, the spoke length is crucial for the strength and lifespan of the nipple. An industrial 36 spoke wheel with a strong heavy rim, brass nipples and a hub gear? Don't overcomplicate it.